# How to sort connection type into only 2 rows in Qlik sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a column named `Con_TYPE` in which there are multiple types of connections such as `fiberoptic`, `satellite`, `3g` etc.

And I want to sort them only into 2 rows:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| fiberoptic | 5 |
| others | 115 |

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Calculated dimension](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Dimensions/calculated-dimensions.htm) or [Mapping load](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Mapping.htm)

Lets imagine that the data, in its raw form, looks like this:

[image: Raw data]

- dimension: `Con_TYPE`
- measure: `Sum(value)`

### Calculated dimension

You can add expressions inside the dimension. If we have a simple `if` statement as an expression then the result is:

[image: Calculated dimension]

- dimension: `=if(Con_TYPE = 'fiberoptic', Con_TYPE, 'other')`
- measure: `Sum(Value)`

### Mapping load

`Mapping load` is a script function so we'll have to change the script a bit:

```
// Define the mapping. In our case we want to map only one value:
// fiberoptic -> fiberoptic 
// we just want "fiberoptic" to be shown the same "fiberoptic"
TypeMapping:
Mapping 
Load * inline [
Old, New
fiberoptic, fiberoptic
];

RawData:
Load
    Con_TYPE,
    value,
// --> this is where the mapping is applied
//     using the TypeMapping, defined above we are mapping the values
//     in Con_TYPE field. The third parameter specifies what value
//     should be given if the field value is not found in the 
//     mapping table. In our case we'll chose "Other"
    ApplyMap('TypeMapping', Con_TYPE, 'Other') as Con_TYPE_Mapped
;
Load * inline [
Con_TYPE  , value
fiberoptic, 10
satellite , 1
3g        , 7
];

// No need to drop "TypeMapping" table since its defined with the 
// "Mapping" prefix and Qlik will auto drop it at the end of the script
```

And we can use the new field `Con_TYPE_Mapped` in the ui. And the result is:

[image: Mapping load]

- dimension: `Con_TYPE_Mapped`
- measure: `Sum(Value)`

### Pros/Cons

- `calculated dimension`

  - `+` easy to use
  - `+` only UI change
  - `-` leads to performance issues on mid/large datasets
  - `-` have to be defined (copy/paste) per table/chart. Which might lead to complications if have to be changed across the whole app (it have to be changed in each object where defined)
- `mapping load`

  - `+` no performance issues (just another field)
  - `+` the mapping table can be defined inline or loaded from an external source (excel, csv, db etc)
  - `+` the new field can be used across the whole app and changing the values in the script will not require table/chart change
  - `-` requires reload if the mapping is changed

P.S. In both cases selecting `Other` in the tables will correctly filter the values and will show data only for `3g` and `satellite`

Comment: Thank you Stefan for putting so much time to answer my question. I really appreciate it. I tried it but it did not work as expected. However, getting inspiration from your code i did research about IF and with a little bit change it worked ))).
=if(Con_TYPE = 'FiberOptic', 'FiberOptic', 'Others')

Comment: If you have time you can look at my another question. Thanks ahead ))))